# Using wget to download GlobColour data from hermes ftp server

Tags: ftp, wget

I want to download the netCDF products from `ftp://ftp.hermes.acri.fr`.
I used `wget` in cygwin package for Windows systems. My link address for accessing to the data is `ftp://ftp.hermes.acri.fr/691969751` and my username and password are `user:ftp_hermes
password:hermes%` as well. So I typed this command in:

```
wget ftp://ftp_hermes:hermes%@ftp.hermes.acri.fr/691969751
```

and I received this message:

```
  --2017-10-30 13:16:18--  ftp://ftp_hermes:*password*@ftp.hermes.acri.fr/691969751
           => ‘691969751’
Resolving ftp.hermes.acri.fr... 213.244.27.35
Connecting to ftp.hermes.acri.fr|213.244.27.35|:21... connected.
Logging in as ftp_hermes ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD not needed.
==> SIZE 691969751 ... done.

==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR 691969751 ...
No such file ‘691969751’.
```

anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are downloading folder recursively. Pass **-r** parameter and it should download the data from FTP server.

```
wget ftp://ftp.hermes.acri.fr/691969751 --ftp-user=ftp_hermes --ftp-pass=hermes% -r 

or

wget ftp://ftp_hermes:hermes%@ftp.hermes.acri.fr/691969751 -r
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it helped. But there was 729 file in the folder and this command read just 129 file and send a successful message.

Comment: It may be ftp connections is getting timeout because of some settings in FTP server or network interruption at your local machine.  If you are having access to the server compress the folder and download.